# Participle clauses after "even"

Tags: participles, adverbials

> You can do that even from home.
> You can do that even when working from home.
> (1)You can do that even working from home.
> (2)?You can do that even living in Korea.

> You can do that even when hurt, angry, or feeling any other emotion.
> (3)?You can do that even hurt, angry, or feeling any other emotion.

Grammatically speaking, sentences 1, 2, 3 all seem sound, with "working from home", "living in Korea" and "hurt, angry, or feeling any other emotion" functioning as participial adverbials modifying their respective subjects. But they don't sound fully natural to my ear, especially (2) and (3). Do they work?

Comment: Little words like that get left out all the time in real speech. Don't worry about it.

Comment: (1) and (2) sound natural. (3) is a little odd. But does *even* even have anything to do with it? *You can do that working from home. You can do that living in Korea. ?You can do that angry.*

Comment: I'd definitely prefer "You can even do that hurt, angry, or feeling any other emotion." But I think it's just a case of alternatives sounding awkward or less natural, not wrong. Maybe to do with where the stress falls - if you want to stress "even" and "hurt" then it's awkward to have them next to each other. In contrast, with "even from home", you have "from" in between.